# How to add camera authorization to http://localhost:8888 in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to access the local camera from a conda jupyter notebook and I get no response.
The same notebook, run in Colab website works perfectly, after asking me to authorize camera access.

In local conda environment I'm not prompted for any authorization and the notebook python script seems to get stuck into a loop when trying to request data from camera.

I've guessed an authorization problem so I've tried to provide such authorization manually.

I'm using Chrome Version 122.0.6261.69 (Official Build) (arm64)

I've entered **chrome://settings/content/all** section, searched for **localhost** and authorized camera access but the result was enabling access from:

```
https://localhost:443
```

What I need, instead, is:

```
http://localhost:8888
```

How can I give that exact authorization?